# Splitting phrase on whitespace, except in acronyms

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking to split phrases on white-space, except when there's a possible acronym. Example:

"Frank worked at I B M forever" -> Frank,worked,at,I B M,forever

Another option would be to "squish" the acronym -> "Frank worked at IBM forever"

Comment: Are these acronyms always in capital letters?

Comment: @hwnd likely not. thx

Comment: Why are there spaces in the middle on the acronym?

Comment: @AndrewM because that's the way the external data is formatted sometimes.

Comment: you might not get around using elasticsearch http://www.elasticsearch.org/case-studies/ and some library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the feature of `split` which allows you to retain the splitting elements by placing them in a capturing group, and make acronyms splitting elements in addition to spaces.

```
var separator = /\s+|\b([A-Z\s]*[A-Z])\b/;
```

This will put some undefineds in the result, so you'll need to filter them out.

```
function split(str) { return str.split(separator).filter(Boolean); }

split("Frank worked at I B M forever")
> ["Frank", "worked", "at", "I B M", "forever"]
```

To remove spaces from between the letters of acronyms:

```
function squish(str) { return str.replace(/\s/g, ''); }
function split(str)  { return str.split(separator).filter(Boolean).map(squish); }

split("Frank worked at I B M forever")
> ["Frank", "worked", "at", "IBM", "forever"]
```

Human-readable version of this regexp:

```
Split on
    white space
    OR
    Between words, capturing as a group
        optional capital letters or whitespace
        followed by a capital letter
```

For more information on this feature of `split`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split:

> If `separator` is a regular expression **that contains capturing parentheses**, then each time `separator` is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, `\b([A-Z]) (?=[A-Z]\b)` seems to work well:

```js
s = "Frank worked at I B M forever"
p = s.replace(/\b([A-Z]) (?=[A-Z]\b)/g, "$1")
document.write(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first request, use this pattern `((?:[A-Z] )+)|` note there is a white space at the end
and replace with `$1,`
then trim extra spaces by replacing `\s?,\s?` w/ `,`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/20)

Comment: Leaves unwanted spaces before the "I" and after the "M".

Comment: hence my comment to trim the extra spaces above.